# GnuPG stuck while generating key

Tags: windows-7, gnupg

I am trying to generate a GPG key using `gpg.exe --gen-key` command. After entering all details including the passphrase the process gets stuck in a loop and keeps repeating the following messages.

```
gpg: NOTE: you should run 'diskperf -y' to enable the disk statistics
gpg: DBG: rndw32: get performance data problem
gpg: NOTE: you should run 'diskperf -y' to enable the disk statistics
gpg: DBG: rndw32: get performance data problem
gpg: NOTE: you should run 'diskperf -y' to enable the disk statistics
gpg: DBG: rndw32: get performance data problem
```

I am using gnupg-w32-1.0.6 on Windows 7. Can anybody help?

Comment: What is rndw32? I believe this is where someone needs to look.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know the cause and fix to the problem above. I tried the same on another machine and it worked. So I just copied the folder `C:\gnupg` to my machine and things started to work normally ever since. Looks like gpg can't generate keys on this machine.

Answer (score 0):

From rndw32.c:

```
    /* Get disk I/O statistics for all the hard drives */
        for (nDrive = 0;; nDrive++) {
            char diskPerformance[SIZEOF_DISK_PERFORMANCE_STRUCT];
        char szDevice[50];

        /* Check whether we can access this device */
        sprintf (szDevice, "\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive%d", nDrive);
        hDevice = CreateFile (szDevice, 0, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                      NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
        if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            break;

        /* Note: This only works if you have turned on the disk performance
         * counters with 'diskperf -y'.  These counters are off by default */
        if (DeviceIoControl (hDevice, IOCTL_DISK_PERFORMANCE, NULL, 0,
                     diskPerformance, SIZEOF_DISK_PERFORMANCE_STRUCT,
                     &dwSize, NULL))
        {
            if ( debug_me )
            log_debug ("rndw32#slow_gatherer_nt: iostats drive %d\n",
                                      nDrive );
            (*add) (diskPerformance, dwSize, requester );
        }
        else {
            log_info ("NOTE: you should run 'diskperf -y' "
                  "to enable the disk statistics\n");
        }
        CloseHandle (hDevice);
        }
```

It seems that the solutions to this, if you were using remote connection, could be this one:
(extracted from microfocus.com)

```
    Enabling Remote Monitoring for Windows XP

    An error message might occur when trying to monitor a computer that is running the Windows XP operating system. If so, enable monitoring remotely.

        Open Windows Explorer on the target Windows XP computer.
        Choose Tools > Folder Options .
        Click the View tab.
        Uncheck the Use Simple File Sharing check box.
        Click OK.
        Verify privileges on the target Windows XP computer as follows:
            If the system root is on an NTFS partition, you must possess at least READ access to the following files:
                %SystemRoot%\System32\Perfc009.dat
                %SystemRoot%\System32\Perfh009.dat
            You must possess at least READ access to the following registry keys on the remote computer:
                HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurePipeServers\winreg
                HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib
        Reboot the Windows XP computer.

    A user who possesses administrator rights to the remote computer can now view the remote counters.
```

If someone is having this problem on a local machine, maybe the answer could be this other way of enabling it:

Check whether it's enabled with this command:

```
    DISKPERF
```

If it's not, try enabling it with:

```
    DISKPERF - Y
```

I know this post is a pair of years old, but since I'm having similar issues using GPG on a Debian OS and I have found quite few complete answers on other sites, I guess it could save some time to others.

BTW, in my case I'm not getting stuck. Maybe the loop you mention is because it's trying to get statics/reports from several disks mounted on your system?